# Building Qt 4.7.4 32 bit libraries on Mac

Tags: qt

I know I have to "./configure" and then make. but which platform do I use? I'd like to use GCC 32-bit on my Mac. what's the equivalent --Platform parameter value for it?

I need to build 32 bit libraries because when I install Qt SDK 1.1.3 (including Qt. 4.7.4) on a clean machine (xCode 4.1 present) I only get 64 bit build options in Qt-Creator in Mac OSX. Although 32 bit tool-chains are available (I can see that by clicking "manage").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify two things, one that it needs to use GCC, and the other that it's 32 bit. GCC is specified with -platform macx-g++42 and the other is just the simple -arch x86